# Can I use my C and A type UK phone charger in the US without voltage converter?

Tags: usa, uk

Can anyone help me out please? I live in the UK. I bought a Duracell 30W C and A type charger for my Google pixel 8 pro and for my power bank to charge. I'm travelling to Costa Rica and wondering if I could use this charger without voltage converter, only with a travel adapter. All my devices are from the UK. Many thanks

Comment: When did the US annex Costa Rica?

Comment: Many chargers accept UK and US voltages, so the answer here will depend upon the input voltages welcomed by your charger. This information is usually stated in a label on the charger, or embossed in its plastic case. What does it say?

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica The [charger](https://www.duracelldirect.co.uk/i/products_large/204838.jpg) is physically a fat British plug with two USB sockets in the side so its specification is for 230V AC and a Type G-style socket, and would presumably work with an adapter elsewhere with 220-240V AC, though the manufacturer would not promote this. It has some adaptative electronics inside so how it would react to 120V is unclear.

Comment: Look at the text on the underside of the charger. It starts by giving the input voltage range.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica thank you  I checked the paper packaging it comes in, I checked online everywhere, couldn't find it. I emailed to duracell customer  service, no response. I bought on amazon so I had a look on product specs and it says 230V. It's just weird because I thought these gadgets for phones and laptops are made dual voltage rated. I haven't opened the box yet to check the bottom of the charger in case I need to send it back and I won't be able to due to damaged packaging. So I keep digging.

Comment: I suspect it says 230V because it's fitted with a plug that's only (usually) used at 230V. For comparison I've had reasons to contact Anker support (not about a charger, though I like their PowerIQ) and they were very helpful

Comment: @dda, Residential power and residential power outlets in Costa Rica are the same as in the U.S.A.

Answer (score 9):

While the Duracell website stubbornly states that the transformer only supports 230 V, what counts is what is written on the transformer itself (on the underside).

I have found a picture of that text (in the reviews on Amazon UK) where it clearly states it supports 100 to 240 V (and 47 to 63 Hz), which makes it suitable for use anywhere in the world, with just a plug adapter.

The opposite would have been extremely surprising: I haven’t seen a USB or laptop transformer that isn’t compatible with both 110 and 230V in decades.

Comment: thank you  it's really helpful.

Comment: If your laptop or phone is ancient then it might not be compatible.  I had a phone charger once which was not suitable for the US.  At the time, most were compatible but mine was an odd exception.  Fortunately, I also had a car charger and it worked.  You would need a very ancient car to have a problem with that.  This story is old, I'd be surprised if any phone or laptop less than a decade old had a problem.  To be safe, check as this answer describes.  Problems are more likely with larger devices e.g. hairdryers.  Check them in the same way but don't be surprised if they are not suitable.

Comment: +1 Presumably the picture you found is [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zGMu.jpg).